# Rails Routing: can't get helper route function to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, helper

I cannot figure out the magic to getting helper path's to work. My use case is this: "mydomain/articles/some_slug" to use to articles controller with the show action. The URL as given works perfectly. But I can't figure out how to make rails' helpers work for this case.

routes.rb:

```
  get '/articles/:slug',    to: 'articles#show', as: 'article'

   --- or ---

  get '/articles/:slug',    to: 'articles#show'

   --- or changing :slug to :id
```

rails routes (this and similar variations with other --- or --- conditions):

```
  articles GET    /articles/:slug(.:format)                 articles#show
```

I get an undefined method `path_to_article' error. This error occurs under these conditions:

my.html.erb:

```
  <%= path_to_article(locals[:article]) %>

   --- or ---

  <%= path_to_article(id: locals[:article].slug) %>

   --- or ---

  <%= path_to_article(slug: locals[:article].slug) %>
```

However, this code works fine, but I don't like it and this is exactly what I am trying to avoid:

```
<a href="/articles/<%= locals[:article].slug %>">
```

I have also tried with plural and non-plurarl combinations where I could and practically any other random ideas I could come up with or find online. In the end, I can't seem to figure out how to get rails to recognized 'path_to_article()'.

Rails 5.0.2

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rails routes
```

returns :

> - The route name (if any)
> - The HTTP verb used (if the route doesn't respond to all verbs)
> - The URL pattern to match
> - The routing parameters for the route
>
> see:
> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes

Basically, you should append *_path* to the route name in your views to call the routes helper.

In your case, the route name is *articles* so the helper method is *articles_path*.

Comment: I have had that guide open today and, well, I guess that I have spent too much time on small details and I'm missing obvious things. I was so hung up on the path_to_xxx that I had tunnel vision. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use:

```
articles_path(locals[:article])
```

or

```
articles_path(locals[:article].slug)
```

depending on how you have things set up